# Cannot convert value of type 'NSURL' to expected argument type 'NSURLRequest'

Tags: swift, api, nsurl, nsurlrequest

For a POST request, I use this code:

```
private func post(url: String, params: [String: AnyObject], headers: [String: AnyObject]) {

   let url = NSURL(string: apiUrl)!
   let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
   request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
   request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField:  "Content-Type")
   request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Application")

   do {
      request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
   } catch {            
      print("error")

      //POST with completionHandler
      var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in        
        print(data)           
      })        
   }
}
```

and at the line that startst with `var task = ...` I get this error: `Cannot convert value of type 'NSURL' to expected argument type 'NSURLRequest'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line:

```
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
```

and pass in the request... not the url:

```
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
```

Always read the method name you are calling, this is specifically creating a dataTaskWith a REQUEST, xcode should of also highlighted this.

[NSURLSession Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithRequest:)

Comment: Glad to of helped, Good luck with the project